# Why is my pagination for custom post type not working?

Tags: wordpress, pagination

Here is the code I'm using to display the pagination...

```
<?php

global $wp_query;



$big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer



echo paginate_links( array(

'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),

'format' => '?paged=%#%',

'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),

'total' => $wp_query->max_num_pages

) );

?>
```

But when you click next and got to /page/2/ it says "Page Not Found"

what am I doing wrong???

Comment: Are you using pretty permalinks?  if so your format needs to be changed to '/page/%#%'

Comment: Also I have read on the pagination docs about there being a page variable and a paged variable depending on the template. Make sure you use the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

The code above is not working because it is not set for a custom post type.
If you look in the wordpress codex for [paginate_links](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/paginate_links) you will find your code under the

> Basic Example
>   To add pagination to your search results and archives, you can use the following example

and is not working for your query because you have different query_vars, the code you should work with should be from the same codex page:

> Example With a Custom Query
>   When querying a loop with new WP_Query set the 'total' parameter to the max_num_pages property of the WP_Query object.
>   with the query beeing:

```
<?php
$paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
$args = array(
'posts_per_page' => 5,
'category_name' => 'gallery',
'paged' => $paged,
);
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
?>
<!-- the loop etc.. -->
```

and the pagination code:

```
<?php
$big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer
echo paginate_links( array(
'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
'format' => '?paged=%#%',
'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
'total' => $the_query->max_num_pages
) );
?>
```

When working with pagination "Page not found" errors usually are caused by missuning the query vars.